# JPQL - projecting @Embeddable object in query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, dto, mapstruct

Lets say I have this for my domain classes:

```
class A{
  private Integer id;
  private Embded e;
}

@Embeddable
class Embded{
  private String emb;
}
```

and this for my DTO classes:

```
class ADto{
  private Integer id;
  private Embded e;
}

class EmbdedDto{
  private String emb;
}
```

is it possible to query inner `Embded` object as projection of `EmbdedDto`? Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new namespace.ADto(a.id, new namespace.EmbdedDto(a.e.emb)) FROM A a");
```

Is it possible to do it automatically using `MapStruct` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a constructor with embeddable key parameters, just like so:

```
class ADto{
    private Integer id;
    private EmbdedDto e;

    public ADto(Integer id, String emb) {
        this.id = id;
        this.e = new EmbdedDto(emb);
    }
}

@Embeddable
class EmbdedDto{
    private String emb;

    public EmbdedDto(String emb) {
        this.emb = emb;
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
@Query("SELECT new namespace.ADto(a.id, a.e.emb) FROM A a");
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround... Would probably have constructor with 50 args  in a real-world code.

Comment: You can use lombok and its cool features like `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@Builder`

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapStruct to map `A` to `ADto` (guess there's a typo in `ADto` and you meant to include `EmbeddedDto` in stead of `Embedded`.)

Just define a mapper

```java
@Mapper
public interface SomeMapper {

     SomeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SomeMapper.class);

     ADto map(A in);
}
```

Mapstruct will automatically also generate a method for `Embedded` to `EmbeddedDto`

Not sure if this is possible in JPQL (I'm not familiar here, but from your example you can call java), but you could then try:

```java
@Query("SELECT SomeMapper.INSTANCE.map(a) FROM A a");
```